# CSS file cannot be located thymeleaf Spring Boot

Tags: html, css, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm setting up a Spring boot server and I just can't get Thymeleaf to link to the CSS. I know there are a number of similar questions but none of them lead me to an answer.

This is the link included in my "home.html".

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
      href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/styles/main.css}"
      href="../styles/main.css" />
```

bootstrap.min.css links fine but main.css gives me a 404.

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zq4jG.png)

This is what it shows me in the web console under networks, this url takes me to a Whitelabel error

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/styles/main.css
```

Comment: What is the url of the page? is it '/' or something below ?

Comment: What do you mean Yannic? I'm just running it on localhost port 8080.

Comment: the url in your browser if you navigate to home.html. is it just $host.$tld/ or is there something after the '/'
For Example if its localhost:8080/home then you would look for the css in localhost:8080/home/styles/main.css where it isn't

Comment: The URL I am using to access this page is localhost:8080, sorry if we're not talking about the same thing. https://imgur.com/a/KyilF

Comment: hm then the ref looks correct. Just to be sure (since i noticed that you just added this main.css). Did you reboot the spring boot application? And have you tried normal href? thref should not be necessary since you don't build a url based on properties

Comment: I have just tried removing the th:href and using only the regular href and the same error still occurs.I also reboot the application whenever I make a change, I haven't set up the dev tools yet.

Comment: ah i just noticed. you have BOTH attributes in your link tag? th:href AND href? remove the th:href and fix the link of href to ="/styles/main.css" if the error still occurs please post the url of the request that is responded with 404

Comment: This is the URL of the 404 -  http://localhost:8080/styles/main.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default there should be a `static` folder and your css content should be there or `public` all inside `resources`. Look at the springboot console when you run the app and look where it's serving resources from. Example below:

```
Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
```

Based on the info above set your resource location accordingly.

Comment: Solved! Thanks. New folder structure for anyone interested in future. https://imgur.com/a/ONSro and changed the link to <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css" />

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a folder under resources called static and a subfolder called css and move your css files there, something like: `resources/static/css/main.css`

Then call it like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/main.css}"/>
```

Comment: Am I right in saying that the templates and css packages should both be moved inside of this new static folder (resources/static). Or would it just be a css package inside static for now?

Comment: Just the CSS and in case you want to use any js you should also create the is folder

Comment: @gregam3 it depends on what kind of template it is. Is it going to be a static HTML template? Then yes, you can move it to the static folder. Is it going to be a proper Thymeleaf template (or using another template engine), then it should stay in the templates folder.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler(
            "/img/**",
            "/css/**",
            "/libs/**")
            .addResourceLocations(
                    "classpath:/static/img/",
                    "classpath:/static/css/",
                    "classpath:/static/libs/");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{../styles/main.css}" />
```

?

Comment: Yes, the 404 still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Your `styles` folder is located at the root of the classpath; it should be moved to a location that's actually configured by Spring Boot (see ["serving static content" in the Spring Boot reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content)).

In your case, moving `src/main/resources/styles` to `src/main/resources/static/styles` should do the trick.