# Fix location path to .css with Thymeleaf (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, css, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm working on a project with Spring Boot. I have a main.css file under `/src/main/resources/static/css/`

I use this thymeleaf code to inject the .css file into a .html file from the /templates folder:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/main.css}" href="../static/css/main.css" />
```

I can open it respectively via `http://localhost:1126/css/main.css`

I use this .html as a detailed error page. So if an URL doesn't exists, show this .html. If the URL is with "one depth" (for example `localhost:1126/something`) it works fine (.html is shown and .css is loaded).
But if I use URLs with at least "two depths", or even with an "/" at the end (for example `localhost:1126/something/` or `localhost:1126/something/anything`) it doesn't work (.html is shown but .css **IS NOT** loaded).

The problem is that in the second case Spring try to find the .css file under `localhost:1126/something/css/main.css`

Things I've tried so far:
use `th:href="@{/css/main.css}"` instead of `th:href="@{css/main.css}"`

AND

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringBootProjectApplication implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootProjectApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/css/");
    }
}
```

I have found these threads with no answers for my problem:

> [Thymeleaf, IntelliJ and Spring Boot not loading CSS files
> correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49420914/thymeleaf-intellij-and-spring-boot-not-loading-css-files-correctly)
> [Spring Boot, Thymeleaf and CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61553420/spring-boot-thymeleaf-and-css)
> [CSS file cannot
> be located thymeleaf Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46318008/css-file-cannot-be-located-thymeleaf-spring-boot)

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot default BasicErrorController would directly look at src/main/resources/templates/ folder if you add your error html page there as "error.html" you can show that whenever error occurs

Comment: The html is shown correctly, my problem is that if the URL has more than one "tag" from the root (like localhost:port/onetag/anothertag), the css file is not loaded.

Comment: if there isn't any request mapping that handle your uri with one more slash or whatever , that would be an error , I guess I couldn't understand you

Comment: It's perfectly OK that it is an error. The question: why doesn't the css file load with the html in case of URLs which contain at least two "/" (one after port number and one anywhere)?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when my URL had multiple "/". But I did not make any special changes except for changing my css links as follows.

`<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{~/css/main.css}">`

And same with javascript files as well.

On a side note, I don't use @EnableWebMvc annotation. It kinda messes up with automatic SpringMVC configuration.